# How to display a maximum number of rows and automatically create new tables in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, rows

My table has 2 columns and many rows. Writing a table in HTML displays rows one under the other and needs scrolling.

I want to set a fixed number of rows (i.e. 5 rows) so that a "new table" (with the very 2 same columns titles) is displayed next to the first one as soon as the limit of 5 rows is reached.

This allows to see all rows at a glance and avoids thinking about where to break rows.

I made an illustration of this : https://i.postimg.cc/ZKv16T2q/tables-illustration.jpg

I don't know how to do this (is this a HTML, CSS or JavaScript issue?), I hope my post is clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: refer http://jsfiddle.net/96Lhog5g/3/

Comment: @Deepak thanks unfortunately it should look like Header1 + Header2 and rows from 1 to _n_ rows. As soon as the maximum limit (i.e. 5) is reached the other rows (6 to 10) are displayed in a "new table" with the same Header1 and Header2. And it goes on until reaching _n_ rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to show you've tried something.

Answer (score 0):

Someone at reddit gave me a nice answer : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZoYpy

HTML

```
    <table class="table-col">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">/</th>
      <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">/</th>
      <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">/</th>
      <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#1</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#2</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#3</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#4</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#5</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#6</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#7</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#8</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#9</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.table-col {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-col thead, .table-col thead tr {
  height: 52px; /* set the header height */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-col thead, .table-col tbody {
  display: block;
  columns: 3 400px; /* # of columns, min column width */
}

.table-col tr {
  display: flex;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.table-col thead th {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.table-col th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.table-col th:first-child {
  max-width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-col td, .table-col th {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```